# NServiceBus: How do I get a subscriber to start processing messing without using generic host?

Tags: nservicebus

I am modifying the PubSub sample, and have been playing around with the configuration of NServiceBus.  Currently, my EndpointConfig.cs file has configuration like this:

```
Configure.With(new[] { typeof(IEvent), typeof(NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.CompletionMessage) })
            .CustomConfigurationSource(new UserConfigurationSource()
               .Register(() => new MsmqTransportConfig { InputQueue = "Subscriber2InputQueue", ErrorQueue = "error", NumberOfWorkerThreads = 1, MaxRetries = 5 }))
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(true);
```

Now I want to change it to just be a console app without the generic host.  Here's what I changed:

1. Changed the project output to be Console app
2. Changed the startup settings to not invoke the generic host
3. Moved the configuration above to the Main method like this:

   ```
           Configure.With(new[] { typeof(IEvent), typeof(NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.CompletionMessage) })
               .CustomConfigurationSource(new UserConfigurationSource()
                  .Register(() => new MsmqTransportConfig { InputQueue = "Subscriber2InputQueue", ErrorQueue = "error", NumberOfWorkerThreads = 1, MaxRetries = 5 }))
               .DefaultBuilder()
               .XmlSerializer()
               .MsmqTransport()
               .IsTransactional(true);


       Console.ReadLine();
   ```

Is there something else I should be doing to "startup" the subscriber to read messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the Async Pages sample to see how to self-host NServiceBus (like in IIS). You're missing .UnicastBus().LoadMessageHandlers().Start().

Comment: I am assuming you meant to have ".CreateBus()" in between LoadMessageHandler and Start?  I tried that, but the messages in the queue aren't being processed.

Comment: I found the problem. I had already tried adding the ".UnicastBus().LoadMessageHandlers().CreateBus().Start()" to my config, but as you can see on the "Configure.With(...)" part, I referenced the type of message (IEvent) but not the handler (EventMessageHandler).

Answer (score 2):

FYI my config looks something like,

```
_Bus = NServiceBus.Configure.With()
              .DefaultBuilder()
              .Log4Net(new MyLogAppender())
              .XmlSerializer()
              .MsmqTransport()
                  .IsTransactional(false)
                  .PurgeOnStartup(true)
              .UnicastBus()
                  .ImpersonateSender(false)
                  .DoNotAutoSubscribe()
                  .LoadMessageHandlers()
              .CreateBus()
              .Start();
```